# Microservice with Spring-Cloud-Gateway with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, microservices, amazon-ecs

I have a project with Microservice Architecture.

Each service consists of a docker container running .jar file, and another container for the corresponding database.

I have 1 Apigateway(Spring-cloud-gateway) routing all the requests to the correct service.

The problem here is that everything is being ran in one EC2 instance.

[image: my_server]

The application is not too active yet so I'm not having any server issues, but I'm speculating to be very busy starting this upcoming March.

And that is why I'm thinking about splitting these into different lambda functions running Spring Boot Applications with each DB going into different RDS.

But I'm not sure how to structure this using AWS services starting with the Spring Cloud Gateway.

**Questions:**

1. How would I migrate the Spring cloud gateway to AWS? Would I have 1 lambda function running the gateway module? Or is there a way to migrate everything I wrote in my yml file for redirecting to AWS ApiGateway?
2. Would it be a good idea to deploy multiple Spring boot applications to multiple lambda functions for microservice architecture? or should i use ECS + Fargate?...

I'm pretty new to AWS, so I'm not sure what the better choice is..

Comment: WHy do you even need to use Spring Cloud Gateway - which is a non AWS API.  A better choice would be to build an AWS Serverless Solution using all supported AWS SDK/APIs. You can  use API Gateway to invoke various AWS Lambda functions. The Lambda functions are built with the Java runtime API and you can use Java V2 API to interact with any AWS Service that you need to use.

Comment: You could also chain together AWS Service calls to build an orchestration that is invoked in reponse to an HTTP call. To see an example of all of this - look at the AWS example application that analyzes customer feedback and synthesizes audio that is located in the AWS COde Lib. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/comprehend_example_cross_FSA_section.html